When using emit in vue 3 the router.push() is not working
When emitting a value to parent component the function will work, but the router.push() does not change the page url as expected.
Here is my function:
function handleRoute(value: string) {
  let url = `/company/sites/${value}`;

  console.log(url);

  router.push(url)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Navigation successful!');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Navigation failed:', error);
  });
}

When using a button to trigger that function the router.push() will work just fine, but when emitting from its child component the url will not change even though it shows Navigation is successful.
<SiteCard :siteData="site.site_name" :siteID="site.site_id" :is_existing="true"
:class="{ 'active-card': activeCard === site.site_id }" @click="handleCardClick(site, 'site')"
:site="site" @handleUrl="handleRoute" />


Please, provide full code of the SiteCard component. Currently, it is not visible what 'value' is in your case. Ideally, provide a stackblitz that reproduces the issue.

Are you having any warning or error in console, as it might be a case that the route on which you are trying to push does not exist. Also if this is not the case then you need to add code so that the error is easily reproducible.
